# Regular Expression needed to match the following format

Tags: regex

the format is:

19 digits followed by an underscore followed by 4 digits ,followed by an underscore ,followed by 1 digit, followed by an underscore, followed by 1 capital letter, followed by an underscore, followed by 4 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits, followed by an underscore, followed by 2 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits and ending with a `".db"`extension

Here are a few filenames, as i thought the above information would be boring to read. :) thanx in advance to anyone who answers.

`2408002705100010002_0002_0_V_2012-11-02_06-35-24.db`
`2408002705100010001_0001_0_V_2012-11-05_05-32-06.db`
`2408001000200000002_0002_0_E_2012-03-03_00-20-06.db`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? In what language will you be using the regex?

Comment: The description seems pretty direct, what did you try?

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: The following regex works using the online tool http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html  

    \d{19}_\d{4}_\d_[A-Z]_\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d_\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.db

Comment: Ah! geez...I was about to post my answer! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d{19}_\d{4}_\d_[A-Z]_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.db`

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - a website to test your RegEx

but I noticed that for example, in the middle you have sth like `_0002_`

Do you accept any 4 digits or those that start with "000"?

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{19}_\d{4}_\d_[A-Z]_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.db
```

This one also does a **basic** check on the date/time part (assuming date YYYY-MM-DD):

```
\d{19}_\d{4}_\d_[A-Z]_\d{4}-(0(?!0)|1(?=[0-2]))\d-(0(?!0)|[1-2]|3(?=[0-1]))\d_([0-1]|2(?=[0-3]))\d(-[0-5]\d){2}\.db
```

**Basic** check means you can still insert dates like February 30th, but not January 32nd.

Comment: thanx a lot for the help. gonna use this solution in my php project

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data:

```
\d{19}_0+\d_0_(V|E)?_(-?(\d{2}|\d{4}))+_(-?\d{2})+\.db
```

If seeking more generic:

```
\d{19}_\d+_\d_[A-Z]?_\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}_(-?\d{2})+\.db
```

HTH

EDIT: On a side note, I would rather split this string with `_`, and then validate each section individually based on some pattern and/or property. That way you will have more control over how this string must look.